# Deserialize with .NET SoapFormatter

Tags: c#, .net, dll, ironpython, soapformatter

I have an C# application which exports data by the `SoapFormatter`. This data should be imported by an application running in an IronPython environment. For this the .NET `SoapFormatter` is used.
The data is contained in classes derived from base classes. The base classes are contained in a DLL. The derived classes are in the namespace of the exporting C# app. To include the classes in the IronPython environment I created an extra DLL with the data structures of them in the same namespace as the C# app has.
This works fine for the first pieces of data. But when it reaches the key

```
<SOAP-ENC:Array id="ref-8" xmlns:a4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/ns/System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[XxxLibrary.Object, XxxLibrary, Version=1.0.0" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="a4:_x0030__x002C__x0020_Culture_x003D_neutral_x002C__x0020_PublicKeyToken_x003D_null_x005D__x005D_[8]">
  <item href="#ref-10" />
  <item href="#ref-11" />
  <item href="#ref-12" />
</SOAP-ENC:Array>
```

I get following `SerializationException` at `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.ProcessGetType(String value, String xmlKey, String& assemblyString)`:

> Parse Error, no type associated with Xml key a4
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[XxxLibrary.Object, XxxLibrary,
> Version=1.0.0.*x0030__x002C__x0020_Culture_x003D_neutral_x002C__x0020_PublicKeyToken_x003D_null_x005D__x005D*
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

whereby XxxLibrary is the DLL containing the base classes, `Object` is a base class. The item at which this occurs is a list of lists containing items based on `Object`: `list<list<Object>> yyy;` The derived classes contained are like mentioned before in another DLL with another namespace.

Maybe anyone has an idea what happens in the `SoapFormatter` and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Through merging the code for the XxxLibrary into the other DLL code I achived that the key is recognized now. Instead there comes
 
`System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Collections.Generic.List'1[XxxLibrary.Object]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Collections.Generic.List'1[XxxLibrary.Object]]'.`
(I converted the characters for code formatting to ' because formatting would be destroyed)